# Where does the when go?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

In rewriting the following sentence with an infinitive or a gerund, what happens to the **when**?

Mary hates it when she is enclosed in small spaces.

Mary hates being (to be) enclosed in small spaces.

Comment: The when indicates that the hate is felt during situations in which she is enclosed in small spaces. 'Being' does the same.

Comment: er, maybe an interesting question could be asking about why the pronoun "it" is obligatory in your first version: *"Mary hates **it** when she is enclosed in small spaces."* :)

Comment: Removing **it** from the first sentence doesn't seem to change the meaning (?) and makes it a bit easier to figure out what is happening

Comment: You may as well ask "Where does Bob go when I write a sentence about Mary?" You've written different constructions with different words. There is no need for *when* in one of them.

Comment: @Aron If you're finding the comments and answers unhelpful or too complex for what you're after, you might have more luck with http://ell.stackexchange.com, which is for english language learners

Comment: @Some_Guy I'm actually looking for something a bit more technical. Is the 2nd sentence, an example of a reduced clause?

Comment: You should probably rephrase your question then, because as it is it's far too broad.

Answer (score 1):

"When" is a conjunction that hooks a subordinate clause ("she is enclosed") to the main clause ("Mary hates").  When you transformed the sentence, you used a verbal phrase, with either a gerund ("being") or an infinitive ("to be"), as the direct object of Mary's hating.  No subordinate clause, no conjunction.